# How to configure classDumpDir in jacoco?

Tags: java, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I'm able to generate jacoco reports by configuring the javaagent using tcpserver option. But dev classes are not getting dumped to my test project.

I have tried adding classDumpDir in pom.xml

```
                        <classDumpDir>${project.build.directory}/classes</classDumpDir>
```

Not sure under which execution and goal classDumpDir needs to be specified and what is the maven command to execute.

My goal is to fetch the dynamically generated dev classes from remote server to my local machine using classDumpDir or any other option.  It would be great if someone can shed some light on pom.xml  part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Not sure under which execution and goal classDumpDir needs to be specified

`classdumpdir` is an option of JaCoCo Java Agent (see https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/agent.html), from there one can logically assume that it can be specified for `prepare-agent` goal. Even without this knowledge and assumption, there is documentation for `jacoco-maven-plugin` at https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/maven.html , which lists all available goals and their parameters, including `classDumpDir` in `prepare-agent` at page https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/prepare-agent-mojo.html#classDumpDir

Comment: For me runtime classes are generated in server machine after the test execution is competed. I have tried the above approach by setting goal as prepare-agent and classDumpDir inside configuration tag as ${project.build.directory}. But still classes are not getting dumped from my server to client machine

Comment: Because class files are dumped where agent is executed, i.e. in your case - server. tcp connection with agent transfers only coverage data, never classes.

Comment: Thanks for confirming on this Godin